# How to access to an output file with Docker

Tags: c++, docker

I'm writting a C++ program, and want to use Docker on it. The `Dockerfile` looks like the following:

```
FROM gcc:7.2.0
ENV MYP /repo
WORKDIR ${MYP}
COPY . ${MYP}

RUN /bin/sh -c 'make'
ENTRYPOINT ["./program"]
CMD ["file1", "file2"]
```

This program needs two input files (*file1* and *file2*) and is built and executed with as follows:

```
docker build -t image .
docker run -v /home/user/tmp/:/repo/dir image dir/file1 dir/file2
```

These input files are located in the host in `/home/user/tmp/`. In the original repository (`repo/`), the executable is located in its root directory, and the output file generated is saved in the same folder (*i.e.* they look like `repo/program` and `repo/results.md`).

When I run the above `docker run` command, I can see from the standard output that the executable is reading correctly the input files and generating the expected results. However, I hoped the written output file (generated by the program with `std::ofstream`) to be also saved in the mounted directory `/home/user/tmp/`, but its not.

How can I access this file? Is there a straightforward way to get it using the docker volume mechanism?

Docker version is 18.04.0-ce, build 3d479c0af6.

**EDIT**

The relevant code regarding how the program saves the output file `result.md` is the following:

```
std::string filename ("result.md"); // in the actual code this name is not hard-coded and depends on intput, but it will not include / chars
std::ofstream output_file;
output_file.open(filename.data(), std::ios::out);
output_file << some_data << etc << std::endl;
...
output_file.close();
```

In practice, the program is run as `program file1 file2`, and the output will be saved in the working directory, not matter if its the same where `program` is placed or not.

Comment: What happens if you manually run the program from within your instance? `docker run -v /home/user/tmp/:/repo/dir image bash`  Are there any errors in `docker logs`?

Comment: I'm asking because mounting and running a trivial container and then writing to the mounted host directory worked correctly.  I'm wondering if your program is either causing an exception, writing to the wrong location, or possibly not even running.  Manually running the program might help diagnose the issue as well as showing the logs.

Comment: The above command generates an error message returned by the program, which asks for the missing input files. If these input files are given (as in the post but followed by `bash`), it responds a similar error message. I'm going to look into the logs, but cannot tell you right now because `docker ps` does not return container names and have never used `docker log` before. Any way, when I run the command in the post, from the standard output I would say that the binary is being executed as expected.

Comment: Are you missing a "-t" in the docker run command? When you say the docker is generating the correct output files, do you know if they are in the correct place (specifically the mapped volume)? Can you "docker run -ti image bash" and verify they are there? I don't think "repo/results.md" is in "/repo/dir" so you should not see it in the mapped volume.

Comment: Again, the program asks for the missing input parameters, and if I run `docker run -ti -v /home/user/tmp/:/repo/dir image dir/file1 dir/file2 bash` the program will also return an error indicating that there are more arguments than expected. Without `bash` the program runs well, but cannot see the output files with `-ti`. @zero298 I just come to see the logs and looks fine.

Comment: Running out of docker, `results.md` is saved in the working directory. Thus, *inside* the container I think it should be saved in the same directory where the executable is (`repo/`, the container *root* directory), which is the one declared by `WORKDIR`

Comment: How do you specify the path the program saves the result to? Seems your program is saving to `/repo`, but you're only mounting `/repo/dir`. Obviously your file is not saved into the shared dir.

Comment: In the C++ code, it's specified as `std::ofstream output_file`, `output_file.open(filename.data(), std::ios::out)`, where filename is a `std::string` (ej: "result.md"). Then, data is saved to the file via `<<` operator. **EDIT**.  Briefly, the path is given directly as the output filename ("result.md")

Comment: Ok, so you're simply not saving into the mounted directory. Either update your program to allow passing the output path, or modify it to store in the mounted dir. Alternatively, mount the whole `/repo` dir (it would need to contain your program too).

Comment: Is mounting the whole `/repo` directory something that I can do via docker commands? If I try running `docker run` with `/repo` being the shared directory (as `docker run -v /home/user/tmp/:/repo image file1 file2`) the following error is returned: **docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./program\": stat ./program: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled**.

Comment: I think @JakubZalas is correct.  Please show how your program saves files.  If it is saving the outfile as a sibling to the program instead of the mounted directory, you won't see it on the host system in the mounted directory.

Comment: Edited the post to contain some more information regarding how the saving is coded

Comment: I've submitted a simple solution that works for the very same code I used two months ago now. I hope its of your interest. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to be sure to save your file into the mounted directory.  Right now, it looks like your file is being saved as a sibling to your program which is right outside of the mounted directory.

Since you mount with:

```
docker run -v /home/user/tmp/:/repo/dir image dir/file1 dir/file2
```

`/repo/dir` is the only folder you will see changes to.  But if you are saving files to `/repo`, they will get saved there, but not seen on the host system after running.

Consider how you open your output file:

```
std::string filename ("result.md"); // in the actual code this name is not hard-coded and depends on intput, but it will not include / chars
std::ofstream output_file;
output_file.open(filename.data(), std::ios::out);
output_file << some_data << etc << std::endl;
...
output_file.close();
```

Since you set the output file to `"result.md"` with no path, it is going to be opened as a sibling to the program.

If you were to run

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint=/bin/bash image
```

which would open an interactive shell using your image and then run `./program some-file.text some-other-file.txt` and then ran `ls` you would see the output file `result.md` as a sibling to `program`.  That is outside of your mountpoint, which is why you don't see it on your host machine.

---

Consider this program.  This program will take an input file and an output location.  It will read in each line of the `infile` and wrap it in `<p>`.  `/some` is the repository directory.  `/some/res/` is the folder that will be mounted to `/repo/res/`.

I provide 2 arguments to my program through `docker run`, the `infile` and `outfile` both of which are relative to `/repo` which is the working directory.

My program then saves to the `outfile` location which is within the mountpoint (`/repo/res/`).  After `docker run` finishes, `/some/res/out.txt` is populated.

---

### Folder structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── makefile
├── res
│   └── in.txt
└── test.cpp
```

### Commands run:

```
docker build -t image .
docker run --rm -v ~/Desktop/some/res/:/repo/res/ image ./res/in.txt ./res/out.txt
```

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcc:7.2.0
ENV MYP /repo
WORKDIR ${MYP}
COPY . ${MYP}

RUN /bin/sh -c 'make'
ENTRYPOINT ["./test"]
CMD ["file1", "file2"]
```

### makefile:

```
test: test.cpp
    g++ -o test test.cpp

.PHONY: clean

clean:
     rm -f test
```

### test.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cout << "Usage: test [infile] [outfile]" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "All args" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    std::ofstream outfile(argv[2]);

    if (!(infile.is_open() && outfile.is_open())) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open files" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        outfile << "<p>" << line << "</p>" << std::endl;
    }
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

### res/in.txt:

```
hello
world
```

### res/out.txt (after running command):

```
<p>hello</p>
<p>world</p>
```

Comment: Very instructive answer. I can reproduce the example and the `out.txt` file is indeed saved. I only have a more question, regarding a program that would return more than one output file, I guess it would be enough with passing the output path as argument, right?

Comment: PS: I want to thank you and the other users that helped solving the issue. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @EuGENE Yes, I'd say that would definitely be a good option.  Just be sure to have a check in your program to verify that files can be saved to the location.  I suppose the `is_open()` will still tell you that, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: @EuGENE I rejected your edit.  For the example program that I put forth, the `docker run` command is correct.  I just double checked it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like yo post the `Dockerfile` I'm using right now, in the hope it can be useful to somebody. It doesn't need to specify a name or path for output files. Output files are always written in `$PWD`.

```
FROM alpine:3.4

LABEL version="1.0"
LABEL description="some nice description"
LABEL maintainer="user@home.com"

RUN apk update && apk add \
  gcc \
  g++ \
  make \
  git \
  && git clone https://gitlab.com/myuser/myrepo.git \
  && cd myrepo \
  && make \
  && cp program /bin \
  && rm -r /myrepo \
  && apk del g++ make git

WORKDIR /tmp

ENTRYPOINT ["program"]
```

I only need to run:

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/tmp image file1 file2
```

*Inside* the image, the working directory is `tmp` and cannot be changed, which is the one passed to the volume `-v` option. After running the image, all output files will be saved in the corresponding working directory of the host machine.

Comment: I think mounting directly to `/tmp` like that will overwrite anything that was already there and result in unwanted temporary files being saved to the host's file system. `/tmp/output` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply `copying` the files from the container to the host machine. This is the simplest solution that worked in my case.

`sudo docker cp container-id:/path_in_container local_machine_path`

> `container-id` is the id of your docker container which can be found with `docker ps` if it's running or `docker ps -a` if it is stopped.

> `path_in_container` is the path of the file in the container

> `local_machine_path` is the path on your device/computer that you are working with. Please note that this has to be **absolute path**

Here's a working example:

`sudo docker cp f1be7fe58g36:/app/Output/output_plan1.pdf' /Users/hissaan/Programming/Clients Data/testing_this.pdf'`

Solution was tested on mac (m1 pro)