# Generating a png file using ggsave() and Docker

Tags: r, docker, ggplot2

As a first attempt at Docker, I am trying to run some R code to generate a PNG file from a Docker container. I am using WSL 2 with Windows 11 and am only using the Docker CLI, not Docker Desktop.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM r-base

# Modify the date at build time
ARG WHEN

# Execute R from the terminal
RUN R -e "options(repos =  \
   list(CRAN = 'http:/mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/${WHEN}')); \
   install.packages('ggplot2')"

# Create a path in the container
RUN mkdir -p /home/
RUN mkdir /home/code
RUN mkdir /home/results

# Copy the file to a path in the container
COPY ./Code/iris.R /home/code/iris.R

WORKDIR /home/code

# Run iris.R in the container
CMD ["Rscript", "iris.R"]

# Copy iris.png
COPY ./iris.png /home/results/iris.png
```

### Code/iris.R

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
                 color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Sepal Width") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(4, 8), breaks = seq(4, 8, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(2, 5), breaks = 2:5)

ggsave(filename = file.path(getwd(), "iris.png"), plot = p, device = "png")
```

### Replicating the problem in Docker CLI

```
$ docker build --build-arg WHEN=2022-12-10 -t plot .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/10 : FROM r-base
 ---> 3de1ef2039fb
Step 2/10 : ARG WHEN
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ff24cab2714d
Step 3/10 : RUN R -e "options(repos =     list(CRAN = 'http:/mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/${WHEN}'));    install.packages('ggplot2')"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 67b96e10f028
Step 4/10 : RUN mkdir -p /home/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 65e100a0ca92
Step 5/10 : RUN mkdir /home/code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 08506b7b2d44
Step 6/10 : RUN mkdir /home/results
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 149966cff268
Step 7/10 : COPY ./Code/iris.R /home/code/iris.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5bba4c93e928
Step 8/10 : WORKDIR /home/code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1b5a8b7ee36b
Step 9/10 : CMD ["Rscript", "iris.R"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8c9cc56e90f4
Step 10/10 : COPY ./iris.png /home/results/iris.png
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat iris.png: file does not exist
```

I have also tried commenting out the last `CMD` line and the last `COPY` line and running `Rscript iris.R` myself.

```
$ docker build --build-arg WHEN=2022-12-10 -t plot .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/8 : FROM r-base
 ---> 3de1ef2039fb
Step 2/8 : ARG WHEN
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ff24cab2714d
Step 3/8 : RUN R -e "options(repos =     list(CRAN = 'http:/mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/${WHEN}'));    install.packages('ggplot2')"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 67b96e10f028
Step 4/8 : RUN mkdir -p /home/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 65e100a0ca92
Step 5/8 : RUN mkdir /home/code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 08506b7b2d44
Step 6/8 : RUN mkdir /home/results
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 149966cff268
Step 7/8 : COPY ./Code/iris.R /home/code/iris.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5bba4c93e928
Step 8/8 : WORKDIR /home/code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1b5a8b7ee36b
Successfully built 1b5a8b7ee36b
Successfully tagged plot:latest
$ docker run -d plot tail -f /dev/null
dd2395f02f9793f1f4fca53eab904c33f38e9ee0dd3b14bcbdd56cd96693e150
$ docker exec -it dd2395f02f97 bash
root@dd2395f02f97:/home/code# ls
iris.R
root@dd2395f02f97:/home/code# Rscript iris.R
Saving 7 x 7 in image
`geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
root@dd2395f02f97:/home/code# ls
iris.png  iris.R
```

and *here* it appears, but it does **NOT** appear when I try to automate this, as described above.

I also tried adding `--no-cache` and this did not fix the issue. It is not clear to me whether the issue is with `ggsave()` or with Docker.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `COPY ./iris.png /home/results/iris.png` line? The COPY commands are meant for getting data into your image at build time. Since the png file is created at run time via the CMD, it does not exist at build time. See ideas here for getting files out of an image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352610/how-to-access-to-an-output-file-with-docker

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution to the problem, thanks to MrFlick's comment.

The key thing to understand here is that output needs to be stored outside of the container on a local drive. It is also important to understand that the current directory `.` referenced in any statements in the MakeFile will refer to the mounted directory.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM r-base

# Set an environment variable
ENV MAINDIR /home

# Modify the date at build time
ARG WHEN

# Execute R from the terminal
RUN R -e "options(repos =  \
   list(CRAN = 'http:/mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/${WHEN}')); \
   install.packages('ggplot2')"

# Create a path in the container
RUN mkdir -p ${MAINDIR}

# Copy the file to a path in the container
COPY iris.R ${MAINDIR}

WORKDIR ${MAINDIR}

# Run iris.R in the container
CMD ["Rscript", "iris.R"]
```

Notably, the `COPY iris.R` statement will be looking for `iris.R` in the directory which will be mounted.

### [where you want the output]/iris.R

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
                 color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Sepal Width") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(4, 8), breaks = seq(4, 8, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(2, 5), breaks = 2:5)

ggsave(filename = "iris.png", plot = p, device = "png")
```

### Docker CLI

```
$ docker build --build-arg WHEN=2022-12-10 -t plot .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  70.14kB
Step 1/8 : FROM r-base
 ---> 3de1ef2039fb
Step 2/8 : ENV MAINDIR /home
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8b3616ad975
Step 3/8 : ARG WHEN
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f5604ee4de70
Step 4/8 : RUN R -e "options(repos =     list(CRAN = 'http:/mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/${WHEN}'));    install.packages('ggplot2')"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8930de4d0a49
Step 5/8 : RUN mkdir -p ${MAINDIR}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5aa70002ed21
Step 6/8 : COPY /Code/iris.R ${MAINDIR}
 ---> 989fdac672b7
Step 7/8 : WORKDIR ${MAINDIR}
 ---> Running in 708bb8d8b42d
Removing intermediate container 708bb8d8b42d
 ---> 5edaa2e558a1
Step 8/8 : CMD ["Rscript", "iris.R"]
 ---> Running in 2d800c986828
Removing intermediate container 2d800c986828
 ---> dc23f821908a
Successfully built dc23f821908a
Successfully tagged plot:latest
```

and now for the key step:

```
$ docker run -v [where you want the output]:/home/ plot
Saving 7 x 7 in image
`geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

Performing `ls` in that directory yields

```
$ ls
iris.R  iris.png
```

This can be generalized with more complicated folder structures as desired.